# Custom Web API Formatting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've been playing around with asp.net web api, and I noticed that default generated returned json doesn't include the object level key.  I was also wondering how to customize the output of the json string. For example:

Getting a User usually returns

```
{
    "Name": "ChaoticLoki",
    "Age": 22,
    "Sex": "Male"
}
```

I was hoping I could return something like:

```
{
    "data": {
        "Name": "ChaoticLoki",
        "Age": 22,
        "Sex": "Male",
    },
    "success": true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can then create a class wrapping the data and status like this

```
public class JsonResult{
    public object data { get; set;}
    public boolean success { get; set;}
}
```

And then in your Web Api methods, you can do

```
var data = ... //getting from repo
return Json(new JsonResult{data = data, success = true});
```